# Intuition behind the positive slope of LM curve : 'Income must increase'?

Tags: macroeconomics

[Source](http://www.economics.utoronto.ca/jfloyd/modules/islm.html): by [John Floyd](http://homes.chass.utoronto.ca/~floyd/) PhD  (in Economics; U Chicago)

> The intuition behind the positive slope of LM is as follows:
>   An increase in the interest rate reduces the demand for money
>   and an increase
>   in income increases it [the demand for money].
>   To [...] [equalize] the demand for money equal to a constant money supply
>    as the interest rate rises
>   and we move along the LM curve,
>   **the level of income must increase.**

Would someone please explain the bolded? It sounds too imperious and presumptuous:
how MUST a rise in interest rate increase consumers' level of income?
Eg, employers can still refuse to increase salary. Then income would NOT increase?

Answer (score 2):

The actors of an economy have a liquidity demand function $L(Y,i)$ where $Y$ is the real income in the economy and $i$ is the nominal interest rate. This function shows how much money the actors keep. (Not wealth, but wealth that is not tied down assets.) It is assumed in the IS-LM model that $L(Y,i)$ is increasing in $Y$ because if you have more income you also spend more and to do this you need more money. It is also assumed that $L(Y,i)$ is decreasing in $i$. If the interest rates are high you have an incentive to deposit more of your wealth and keep less of it liquid/instantly accessible.

Now the points of the LM (Liquidity - Money Supply) curve are those $(Y,i)$  pairs for which the liquidity demand equals the money supply. Suppose that given some money supply $M$ and price level $P$ you have
$$
L(Y,i) = \frac{M}{P},
$$
so the market for money (liquidity) is in equilibrium. Then this point (Y,i) is on the LM curve. While we keep the exogenous variables $M$ and $P$ unchanged we would like to see if there is another pair (Y',i') such that
$$
L(Y',i') = \frac{M}{P}.
$$
Suppose that $i'>i$. Because the function $L$ is decreasing in $i$ this means $$
L(Y,i') < L(Y,i) = \frac{M}{P} = L(Y',i').
$$
Since $L(Y,i') < L(Y',i')$ and $L$ is increasing in $Y$ we have $Y < Y'$.

Thus if there are two points on the same LM curve and the nominal interest rate is higher in one point, income must the higher in that point as well. I believe this is what Floyd meant.

If you dislike dealing with general function forms you may assume
$$
L(Y,i) = \frac{Y}{i} \mbox { or } \frac{Y}{1+i}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The intertemporal consumption equation is :

$$Y_{1}+\frac{Y_{2}}{(1+r)} = W$$

where $W$ is total wealth and $Y$ is revenue.

When interest rate rise investiment drops and savings rise, so lets say someone choses to save all his revenu from period 1 (this is just to calculate his total wealth), then in period 2 his total wealth will be :

$$Y_{1}(1+r)+Y_{2} = W(1+r)$$

So as you can see his total wealth in 2nd period grows when interest rate grows

Also we can isolate $Y_{1}$ :

$$Y_{1}= W-\frac{Y_{2}}{(1+r)}$$

And you see that when interest rate rises your revenu in period one rises.

I am not sure if this is a valid answer but it seems correct